# Sonarqube Stuck In Process (BulkIndexer) Indexing Elasticsearch. Sonar version 9.9.0-community

Tags: sonarqube

Make sure to tell us:

- What version are you upgrading from? -> 9.3.0-community to 9.9.0-community
- System information (Operating system, Java version, Database provider/version)
  I'm not sure, but I use this chart -> https://SonarSource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube
  database -> postgresql server version 13.13
- What's the issue you're facing? -> when the pod sonarqube is up, it always stuck at process like this

```
2024.03.08 14:36:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [users/user] done | time=467ms
2024.03.08 14:36:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [projectmeasures/auth/projectmeasure]...
2024.03.08 14:37:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:38:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:39:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 1 requests processed (0 items/sec)
```

after that it will be error, and repeate the process BulkIndexer:

```
2024.03.08 14:49:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 4 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:50:17 ERROR web[][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://100.73.3.156:9000/api/system/liveness
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Liveness check failed
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.LivenessActionSupport.checkliveness(LivenessActionSupport.java:55)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.LivenessAction.handle(LivenessAction.java:51)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:111)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:84)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SonarLintConnectionFilter.doFilter(SonarLintConnectionFilter.java:66)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:116)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:68)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CspFilter.doFilter(CspFilter.java:63)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:60)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:47)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:57)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:61)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor601.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:280)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.sonar.server.app.SecureErrorReportValve.invoke(SecureErrorReportValve.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Before this issue happen, I try to upgrade version sonarqube from 9.3.0-community to 9.9.0-community. And I think I already successfully upgrade my DB in postgre

```
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] Starting DB Migration and container restart
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executing DB migrations...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6301 'Drop unused Issues Column REPORTER'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6301 'Drop unused Issues Column REPORTER': success | time=47ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6302 'Drop unused Issues Column ACTION_PLAN_KEY'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6302 'Drop unused Issues Column ACTION_PLAN_KEY': success | time=10ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6303 'Drop unused Issues Column ISSUE_ATTRIBUTES'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6303 'Drop unused Issues Column ISSUE_ATTRIBUTES': success | time=8ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6304 'Create table 'SCANNER_ANALYSIS_CACHE'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6304 'Create table 'SCANNER_ANALYSIS_CACHE': success | time=48ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6305 'Issue warning for users using SHA1 hash method'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6305 'Issue warning for users using SHA1 hash method': success | time=15ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6306 'Drop table 'user_properties''...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6306 'Drop table 'user_properties'': success | time=14ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6401 'Add column 'project_key' to 'user_tokens''...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6401 'Add column 'project_key' to 'user_tokens'': success | time=18ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6402 'Add column 'type' to 'user_tokens''...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6402 'Add column 'type' to 'user_tokens'': success | time=12ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6403 'Upsert value of type in 'user_tokens''...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6403 'Upsert value of type in 'user_tokens'': success | time=14ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6404 'Make column 'type' in 'user_tokens' not nullable'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6404 'Make column 'type' in 'user_tokens' not nullable': success | time=5ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6405 'Create table RULE_DESC_SECTIONS'...
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6405 'Create table RULE_DESC_SECTIONS': success | time=18ms
2024.03.08 14:07:10 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6406 'Insert description from RULES into RULE_DESC_SECTIONS'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6406 'Insert description from RULES into RULE_DESC_SECTIONS': success | time=868ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6407 'Create index for RULE_DESC_SECTIONS'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6407 'Create index for RULE_DESC_SECTIONS': success | time=115ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6408 'Drop column DESCRIPTIONS from RULES table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6408 'Drop column DESCRIPTIONS from RULES table': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6409 'Drop column CREATED_AT from RULES_METADATA table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6409 'Drop column CREATED_AT from RULES_METADATA table': success | time=11ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6410 'Drop column UPDATED_AT from RULES_METADATA table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6410 'Drop column UPDATED_AT from RULES_METADATA table': success | time=8ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6411 'Overwrite plugin file hash to force reloading rules'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6411 'Overwrite plugin file hash to force reloading rules': success | time=7ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6412 'Add rules_metadata columns to rules table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6412 'Add rules_metadata columns to rules table': success | time=117ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6413 'Populate rules metadata in rules table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 0 rows processed (0 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6413 'Populate rules metadata in rules table': success | time=17ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6414 'Drop rules_metadata table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6414 'Drop rules_metadata table': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6415 'Migrate hotspot rule descriptions'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6415 'Migrate hotspot rule descriptions': success | time=286ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6416 'Remove onboarded column from User table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6416 'Remove onboarded column from User table': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6417 'Add column 'user_triggered' to 'audits''...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6417 'Add column 'user_triggered' to 'audits'': success | time=14ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6418 'Upsert value of 'user_triggered' in 'audits''...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6418 'Upsert value of 'user_triggered' in 'audits'': success | time=5ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6500 'remove root column from users table'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6500 'remove root column from users table': success | time=8ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6501 'Add columns 'context_key' and 'context_display_name' into rule_desc_sections'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6501 'Add columns 'context_key' and 'context_display_name' into rule_desc_sections': success | time=29ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6502 'Drop unique index uniq_rule_desc_sections_kee'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6502 'Drop unique index uniq_rule_desc_sections_kee': success | time=10ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6503 'Create unique uniq_rule_desc_sections'...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6503 'Create unique uniq_rule_desc_sections': success | time=101ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6504 'Add column 'expiration_date' to 'user_tokens''...
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6504 'Add column 'expiration_date' to 'user_tokens'': success | time=11ms
2024.03.08 14:07:11 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6505 'Add column 'rule_description_context_key' to 'issues''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6505 'Add column 'rule_description_context_key' to 'issues'': success | time=11ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6506 'Add column 'education_principles' to 'rules''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6506 'Add column 'education_principles' to 'rules'': success | time=12ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6507 'Overwrite plugin file hash to force reloading rules'...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6507 'Overwrite plugin file hash to force reloading rules': success | time=4ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6508 'Migrate 'sonarlint_ad_seen' from users to properties'...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 106 rows processed (1 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6508 'Migrate 'sonarlint_ad_seen' from users to properties': success | time=21ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6509 'Drop column sonarlint_ad_seen in 'users''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6509 'Drop column sonarlint_ad_seen in 'users'': success | time=8ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6510 'Create table 'push_events''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6510 'Create table 'push_events'': success | time=15ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6511 'Create index 'idx_push_even_crea_uuid_proj' on 'push_events''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6511 'Create index 'idx_push_even_crea_uuid_proj' on 'push_events'': success | time=19ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6512 'Add column 'language' to 'push_events''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6512 'Add column 'language' to 'push_events'': success | time=10ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6513 'Delete duplicated rows in 'project_badge_token''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6513 'Delete duplicated rows in 'project_badge_token'': success | time=7ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6514 'Add unique index on 'project_uuid' in 'project_badge_token''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6514 'Add unique index on 'project_uuid' in 'project_badge_token'': success | time=13ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6600 'Add column 'webhook_secret' to 'alm_settings''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6600 'Add column 'webhook_secret' to 'alm_settings'': success | time=10ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6601 'Drop non unique index on 'uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6601 'Drop non unique index on 'uuid' in 'components'': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:07:12 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6602 'Add unique index on 'uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6602 'Add unique index on 'uuid' in 'components'': success | time=15191ms
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6603 'Drop index for 'project_uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6603 'Drop index for 'project_uuid' in 'components'': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6604 'Rename column 'project_uuid' to 'branch_uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6604 'Rename column 'project_uuid' to 'branch_uuid' in 'components'': success | time=15ms
2024.03.08 14:07:27 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6605 'Create index for 'branch_uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6605 'Create index for 'branch_uuid' in 'components'': success | time=4801ms
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6606 'Drop index for 'kee' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6606 'Drop index for 'kee' in 'components'': success | time=14ms
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6607 'Fix copy component UUID'...
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 0 rows processed (0 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6607 'Fix copy component UUID': success | time=638ms
2024.03.08 14:07:32 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6608 'Remove branch information from 'kee' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:08:32 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 452749 rows processed (7545 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:09:32 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 870249 rows processed (6958 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:10:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 1281355 rows processed (6851 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:10:29 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6608 'Remove branch information from 'kee' in 'components'': success | time=176986ms
2024.03.08 14:10:29 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6609 'Add unique index on 'kee','branch_uuid' in 'components''...
2024.03.08 14:11:08 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6609 'Add unique index on 'kee','branch_uuid' in 'components'': success | time=38474ms
2024.03.08 14:11:08 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6700 'Move live measure variations to values'...
2024.03.08 14:12:08 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 585499 rows processed (9758 items/sec)
.
.
etc (text is too long)
2024.03.08 14:27:34 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6700 'Move live measure variations to values': success | time=986240ms
2024.03.08 14:27:34 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6701 'Drop live measure variation column'...
2024.03.08 14:27:34 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6701 'Drop live measure variation column': success | time=112ms
2024.03.08 14:27:34 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6702 'Move project measure variations to values'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.s.MassUpdate] 31218 rows processed (520 items/sec)
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6702 'Move project measure variations to values': success | time=8883ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6703 'Drop project measure variation column'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6703 'Drop project measure variation column': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6704 'Update sonar-users group description'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6704 'Update sonar-users group description': success | time=8ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6705 'Add message_formattings column to issue table'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6705 'Add message_formattings column to issue table': success | time=13ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6706 'Create scim_users table'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6706 'Create scim_users table': success | time=50ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6707 'Create unique index on scim_users.user_uuid'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6707 'Create unique index on scim_users.user_uuid': success | time=34ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6800 'Add node_name column to ce_activity table'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6800 'Add node_name column to ce_activity table': success | time=18ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6801 'Delete all analysis cache'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6801 'Delete all analysis cache': success | time=3ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6802 'Change user_uuid field size to 255 for audit table'...
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #6802 'Change user_uuid field size to 255 for audit table': success | time=9ms
2024.03.08 14:27:43 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: success | time=1233577ms
```

I also read from post https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-deployment-failing-to-start-in-kubernetes-due-to-liveness-check-failed/73252, that say it need to adjust the liveness. But I try adjust to:

```
readinessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 600
  periodSeconds: 300
  failureThreshold: 60
  timeoutSeconds: 10
livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 600
  periodSeconds: 300
  failureThreshold: 60
  timeoutSeconds: 10
startupProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 300
  periodSeconds: 100
  failureThreshold: 240
  timeoutSeconds: 10
```

it still same

How to debug and solve it? I just curious why from that logs it always says **0 items/sec**

```
2024.03.08 14:50:51 INFO  web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 5 requests processed (0 items/sec)
```